# Akka and Play on Heroku: Should I have my actors on seperate dyno or in the web dyno?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, playframework-2.0, akka

I'm trying to setup some actors and curious how to bundle Actors with Play.
I see that Play! comes bundled already with Actors but it requires the full Application context.
That means to deploy the actors I'd also have to deploy the web application.
Is this a good way forward or do people deploy actors separately on a worker dyno separate from the Play application?

PS: I'd love for an example :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a small job and you think that the number of users visiting your website in parallel is small, they you can do it in the same application. Else its better to deploy it separately, if it's a process with high memory usage and load on the server.

You can refer this repository for an example.
https://gist.github.com/phyous/5991288